# trying to work with EDSDK from Canon using Xcode

Tags: xcode, edsdk, canon-sdk

just tried to install the EDSDK framework into the Xcode project framework folder. However I cannot run anything, as I am getting a lot of error messages. for example at this position in the EDSDK.h file:

```
EdsUInt32 EDSAPI EdsRetain(  EdsBaseRef  inRef );
```

I get the error message:

> A parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition

I get these all over the place. I really would like to make an MacOS app that takes an image and saves an image with a certain name.

Answer (score 0):

The EDSDK should include two sample XCode projects written in Objective-C, namely:

- CameraControl -- controlling the camera
- RawDevelop -- processing (raw) images downloaded from the camera

If you'd like to skip the Objective-C part, you could bridge this into Swift yourself. Alternatively, have a look at the most recent PowerShot G7X SDK where Swift is used to make a similar example project.

Comment: I tried to load the PowerShot project, but it has many errors, and after solving them, it still does not start. I tried again to build it my self. The project is being build, but somehow it does not find the EDSDK library file: dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/EDSDK.framework/Versions/A/EDSDK